# Free treemapping software

Tags: data-visualization, software

Is there any free desktop software for [treemapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping)? [Every one I've found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_treemapping_software) appears to have a commercial license. [Many Eyes](http://manyeyes.alphaworks.ibm.com/manyeyes/) is free and has treemapping features but what I'm really looking for is downloadable desktop software.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Flowing Data has a tutorial](http://flowingdata.com/2010/02/11/an-easy-way-to-make-a-treemap/) on how to use the `map.market` function in the `portfolio` package in R.

Comment: Thanks, Jeromy. Actually this is even better than what I asked.

Answer (score 6):

**Protovis** has an [nice treemap layout](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/treemap.html).  I could try to add this into [webvis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webvis/index.html) if you want to create it from R, but it isn't currently an option.

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't used either of these, I have these two projects bookmarked:

- [Treeviz](http://www.randelshofer.ch/treeviz/index.html)
- [JTreeMap](http://jtreemap.sourceforge.net/)

Both are implemented in Java, are free and open source (MIT and Apache 2.0 licenses, respectively). Both appear to be actually libraries, but seem to come with an example application.

Answer (score 1):

While commercial, Macrofocus provides a free 30-days evaluation of their [TreeMap](http://www.macrofocus.com/public/products/treemap/) software.

Answer (score 1):

The treemap package for R is superior - better look, much more flexible - to the map.market function in package portfolio featured in FlowingData's tutorial.