# Best open source data visualization software to use with PowerPoint

Tags: data-visualization, excel, software, open-source

What is the best open source data visualization software? I require the following:

1. Can import data from Microsoft Excel (importing data from Oracle databases would be good too, but this is not mandatory).
2. Charts generated by the software can be exported to Microsoft PowerPoint (copy and paste is fine with me).
3. Open source & easy to use.

Comment: Is there a requirement that it run locally on a system? Is there a platform restriction (Win/Mac)?

Comment: [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) in Python, [ggplot2](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5051_39c30acbb432498fa1a290f166c6b403.html) in R. Both can export to various formats -- both raster and vector -- but you will need to learn to work with their respective languages.

Comment: What kind of charts are you making? If you are using Excel and powerpoint, why not just use native charts? This way if the data changes, the slides can change relatively easily. Using a third-party solution will mean having to resave data, export, graph, and copy back into a powerpoint.

Comment: I would recommend switching from powerpoint to use auto generated presentations using Rmd and pandoc. Also selecting your data automatically from a database (as you suggest you already do) would greatly streamline your process. Once the data change or if you would like to followup a few weeks after all you have to do it rerun the script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated 2017-02-24**:

I think that the best solutions is to use R with [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/).  ( Python and iPython notebook is an alternative ):

- Data import

  - Excel: [readxl](https://cran.r-project.org/package=readxl) package
  - Oracle: [ora](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ora) or [RODBC](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RODBC) package
- Plotting: [ggplot2](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2)
- Exporting plots

  - Copy-and-paste: RStudio's exports plot functionality
  - Programatically: [ReporteRs](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/) package

### TLDR;

#### Data Import

There are numerous ways to import excel (tabular) data. For Excel data, the `readxl` package provides the easiest and most versatile. It generally gets the variable types correct on import.

Alternatives are to save the file as CSV and re-import. The `readr` package is good for this. @Nick Stauner provides perhaps the most basic solution using `read.csv`; the limitation is that this requires the additional step of saving a worksheet as a CSV file.  This is not great if your data is spread across multiple sheets.  It can get tedious though there are VBA programs for saving all sheets as CSV files. Google for them. Another limitation is getting the types of the variables correct.  If you use `read.csv`, you often have to fix your types after importing in R.

There are a few packages that avoid these problems by allowing you to connect read/write  from the spreadsheet directly or by using ODBC.  Search on CRAN for *excel* or *odbc* to find the relevant one for your situation.

#### Plotting

In terms of getting plots into powerpoint, use Rstudio's export plot functions, the copy and paste method using *Rstudio* is:

`export plot` > `copy plot to clipboard` > `copy as:  metafile` captures the plot to the the paste buffer allowing you to paste directly into Power Point.

As far as generating plots, R has numerous options. The aforementioned *ggplot2* package provides a very powerful interface for creating all sorts of plots.  There are additional packages for doing hundreds or thousands of other types of plots/animations/etc.  One limitation is that these are often buried in [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) packages.

An alternative is to use the ReporteRs package.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know about "best", but the software environment you're named after fits all your requirements:

- I keep my data in Excel spreadsheets; when I'm ready to import them to R, I save as CSV and use `read.csv()`.

  - The `RODBC` and `ora` packages are available for importing from Oracle.
- Images produced in R can be copied as bitmaps or metafiles and pasted directly into PowerPoint. You can find plenty of recommendations here for R as an open-source data visualization utility:

  - [Open source tools for visualizing multi-dimensional data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/196/32036)
  - [Does anyone know any good open source software for visualizing data from database?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44204/32036)
  - [Software for easy-yet-robust data exploration](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9085/32036)
  - [Resources for learning to create data visualizations?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2171/32036)
  - [Resources for learning to use (/create) dynamic (/interactive) statistical visualization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6375/32036)

    - [R: update a graph dynamically](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6021/32036)!
  - [How can I create nice graphs automatically?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18771/32036)
  - [Web visualization libraries](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/216/32036)
  - [Free treemapping software](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2099/32036)
  - [Recommended visualization libraries for standalone applications](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224/32036)
  - Other suggestions in these threads are worth considering too, but I haven't tried them.
  - More enthusiasm about R in general (not just for data visualization):

    - [What are some valuable Statistical Analysis open source projects?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3/32036)
    - [What is your favorite, easy to use statistical analysis website or software package?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3958/32036)
    - vs. [Python as a statistics workbench](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1595/32036) ... a close contest at least!
- R is open-source. Though its learning curve is nontrivial, it becomes easy to use with experience.

Comment: A non-original quip: The learning curve is steep. If you put in a little effort, you learn a lot. (Otherwise put, it's vital to know which variable is on which axis.)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Nick Stauner](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/32036/nick-stauner) on R. And, with a username like "R Learner" I was tempted to not suggest other tools, but there are many. I'll wait to see what the answer to my questions are for more platform-specific ones, but [Mondrian](http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/mondrian/) is a Java desktop program (so cross-platform) and supports many visualization types that you can easily get into PowerPoint.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestion. Definitely I will try those packages in R.@hrbrmstr,yes I want to run it locally in my windows system